# Swipe function calls multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've created a simple JavaScript file in which I have 2 images.

Here the person can either swipe left or right & accordingly images swipes.

Here's my code,

```
$('#landscapeimage1').swiperight(function (event) { //here lanscapeimage1 is canvas on which i have drawn an image.

    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var slide = "+=" + width + "px";
    $('#landscapeimage').animate({
        'left': -width
    }, 1, function () {
        $('#landscapeimage1').animate({
            "left": slide
        }, "fast", function () {});
        $('#landscapeimage').animate({
            "left": slide
        }, "fast", function () {
            currentImage = getPreviousImage();
            currentCanvas = "landscapeimage";

            drawImage();
            $(this).unbind(event);
            return false;
        });
        return false;
    });

    return false;
});
```

**Initially when I swipe it works properly but if I visit the same image then it calls the same function again & again until unvisited images does not come & if I have visited all images then it turns into an infinite loop.**

I don't understand why this happens.

I've tried to stop animate & unbind swipe function but that's also not working.

```
<div data-role="page" id="imagepage">

            <div class="whiteBackground" id="landscapeimage" style="position: relative;">
                <canvas id="image" style="z-index: 1;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;" height="200px" width="200px">
                </canvas>
                </div>

<div class="whiteBackground" id="landscapeimage1" style="position: relative;">
                <canvas id="image1" style="z-index: 1;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;" height="200px" width="200px">
                </canvas>
                </div>

        </div>
```

**After debugging I've found that the animate function is calling multiple times; not the swipe function, but I can't figure out why? Please help me out.**

Does any body know why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Your code had issue:

```
$('#landscapeimage1').off().swiperight(function (event) { 
    //code here
    return false;
});
```

Or:

```
var flag = true;
    if( flag ){
       // Set flag
       flag = false;
       $('#landscapeimage1').swiperight(function (event) { 
       //code here
       return false;
    });
}
```

Because, event fire many time when you swipe: 1 at once, 1+1 at twice and more..

Comment: then where flag i can set?